# AngularJS DOM selector

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a few custom directives that use jQuery for animation effects (angular's built-in ngShow/ngHide and the like are functional, but not pretty). I think I remember reading in the documentation somewhere that angular has its own DOM selector (something like `angular.export()` or `angular.select()`) that I should use instead of `$(SELECTOR)`; however I can't find it now.

I'm doing something like this:

```
//view
<div scroll-to="element"> //`element` is set via ng-click
  …
</div>

//directive
link: function(scope, elm, attrs)
{

  scope.$watch(attrs.scrollTo, function scrollToAction(newValue,oldValue)
  {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue )
    {
      elm.animate({
        scrollTop:
          $('#'+newValue).offset().top //replace jquery selector with angular's
          - elm.offset().top
          + elm.scrollTop()
      });
    }
  });

}
```

I'm not really manipulating `$('#'+newValue)`, just retrieving info about it, so I don't think I'm committing a crime against Angular.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"jqLite" (defined on the [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) page) provides DOM traversal methods like `children()`, `parent()`, `contents()`, `find()`, `next()` (but not `previous()`).  There is no selector-like method.

You might want to try JavaScript's [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector).

Comment: +1 I've also added additional information that might explain why the OP feels he's seen an angular method that you could select elements with.

Comment: Ah thanks, yes that's exactly it. I do include jquery before angular, so is `angular.element()` still preferable? It seems like it would just add extra overhead of resolving the alias.

Comment: @jacob, I would use `angular.element()` so that if in the future your code no longer needs jQuery, you won't have to update it.

Answer (score 39):

As the [official AngularJs doc says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> All element references in **Angular** are *always wrapped* with **jQuery** or **jqLite** (such as the element argument in a directive's compile / link function). They are never raw DOM references.

In details: if you include **jQuery** *before* your Angular reference, the `angular.element()` function becomes an alias for jQuery (it's otherwise `jqLite`, see Mark Rajcok's answer).

---

You can check in the Dev Tool debugger if you are getting jQuery or jqLite by placing a breakpoint at the line where you call `angular.element()`. When hovering it, you will be prompted for the relevant library, see screenshot below (in my case, I get jQuery).

[image: jQuery for <code>angular.element()</code>]

---

As the [official AngularJs doc says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

> For lookups by tag name, try instead `angular.element(document).find(...)` or `$document.find()`

In other words: if you get jQuery when calling `angular.element()`, then anything like `angular.element('#foo > bar')` works if that's what you're thinking of.

---

If you're wondering how to get this selector feature without jQuery, then you may want to use [Sizzlejs](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle). [Sizzle is the selector library that jQuery uses under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785978/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-the-sizzle-javascript-library).