# Building a Web App in AngularJS without jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've built web app using Angularjs,jQuery,jQueryUI, I want to know is it possible to build the web without jQuery ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should learn angularjs without jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416592/should-learn-angularjs-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS does not require jQuery. When it comes to navigating and manipulating the DOM, it comes with its own limited API called [jQuery Lite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), which contains a subset of jQuery functionality with only the essentials. Additional things like ajax are omitted, because Angular does it a different way and therefore it isn't needed.

If you need to use jQuery along with AngularJS (say you need some specific functionality from jQuery, or you are using a jQuery component in your AngularJS app), you can include the jquery.js file before the angular.js file, and Angular will use jQuery instead of jQLite.

jQuery UI is a different story, as it contains widgets for different UI elements. AngularJS does not have any built-in UI widgets. However, you can still use jQuery UI in an AngularJS app. However, there are caveats to note when using non-Angular components inside an Angular app so that they function properly together. It's harder to explain why that is until you have a better understanding of how Angular works, and I feel like that's outside the scope of this question. There is material available on the [angularjs.org website](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts). However, [here's an article](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html) on getting jQuery UI components to work best within Angular.

There are separate modules being developed to provide commonly used widgets. For example, [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) uses the Twitter Bootstrap CSS and recreates the widgets in pure Angular directives.

**Short answer**: Yes, you can create web applications completely in AngularJS without the use of jQuery or jQuery UI.