# element vs. this in AngularJS Directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Once jQuery is included in Angular, inside directives one is free to use both $(element) and $(this) for DOM manipulations.

What is the difference between them? Is one recommended over the other? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` will depend on the context of the method being executed, `$(element)` will always refer to the the directive is attached to.

here's a contrived example

```
module.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        template: '<div><button id="btn">Click Me</button></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                $("#btn").on('click', function() {
                    // $(this) != $(element)
                    // $(this) is the button element from the template
                    // $(element) is the directive element
                });
            }
        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since angular js is using jqlite(a minimal version of jquery)under the hoods  for selectors,it may be the same in angular js also with different name.

Refer:
[AngularJS DOM selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280463/angularjs-dom-selector)

Comment: Intersting answer to know more about this keyword in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword