# Using jQuery to select element created by ng-repeat in Angular JS directive by class?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, traversal

I've looked at the documentation on the Angular site [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) but I'm still a little bit confused.

I have an angular directive who's template contains elements created by `ng-repeat`. Each of these elements has a common class. I'm trying to select those elements by class so that I can pass a handler when an event is triggered on an element belonging to that class.

As far as I can tell from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280463/angularjs-dom-selector) I have the option of selecting those elements with `jqLite` or `angular.element()`. My jQuery is included AFTER Angular is included. I assume that this should be done this way because I want to select elements of a specific class AFTER Angular has produced them through my directive.

I'm not actually trying to use the `.click()` event on the class, it's just a proof of concept. I have the following code in the controller associated with the containing element of the directive:

```
$(".gallery-image").click(function(){
        alert("test");
});
```

What I'm attempting to do should be fairly apparent, I'm just unsure how to deal with this cocktail of Angular and jQuery.

How would I select and run an event handler with jQuery on these elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use it like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".gallery-image", function(){
        alert("test");
});
```

you cannot select directly on `".gallery-image"` because there is none of them are on page in the moment when you bind click event on to them

But you always can use `ng-click` directive on items in `ng-repeat` you don't need to use jQuery to bind click event.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post, `.click()` was just a placeholder. I don't want to use CSS3 for a number of reasons, and I'm going to use jQuery's `.animate()` method. This code works perfectly. I'm unsure exactly why it does, though. We're selecting the document with jQuery then selecting a DOM element belonging to it. The `.click()` method is specifically mentioned in the jQuery documentation as being equivilent to your `.on()` method. How is this any different?

Comment: @Allenph [Event Delegation & Propagation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Yes but with one big difference, .on() bind events on "live", so if you add new DOM elements it will bind event to them, but when you use only .click() you bind event only to elements that are on page at the moment. you can find more explanation on here http://api.jquery.com/on/  Delegated events

Comment: @AleksandarGajic, so then we could use the `.on()` method without the selector, and simply select the element by class. I.E. `$("#className").on("click", function(){});`?

Comment: @AleksandarGajic nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you load `jQuery` after `Angular`, the [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) keeps as the simplified version of jQuery: jqLite.

> To use jQuery, simply ensure it is loaded before the angular.js file.

So you need to load jQuery first. You can check on the console through `angular.element === jQuery`.

If you contain `ng-repeat`, always use `$timeout` to wait for the rendering finishes. Then you can access the elements.

But of course, whenever possible, always use `ng-click` instead of `.on('click',...`.